# Clone() the first class in jquery

Tags: jquery, clone

```
$('.addPack').click(function(){
            $('.immediate-whiskypack-inputs').clone().appendTo('#whiskypacks').show();
            return false;
       });
```

I have some form inputs in a div.immediate-whiskypack-inputs, I want to clone this and append it to div#whiskypacks.
The above function clones each div class, is there a way of cloning just one of the div's?

Comment: Sure, which one do you want to clone?

Comment: @JeffB: Whatever, he can use `eq` :)

Comment: Unless he wants to clone whichever one has an input value of "awesome"...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply modify your selector so that it returns the single element that you want to clone. If you're interested in the first match, then use:

```
$('.immediate-whiskypack-inputs:first')
```

rather than

```
$('.immediate-whiskypack-inputs')
```

Answer (score 6):

> The above function clones each div class, is there a way of cloning
>   just **one of the div's**?

Use `eq`<sup>[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)</sup>:

```
$('.immediate-whiskypack-inputs').eq(0).clone().appendTo('#whiskypacks').show();
```

The `eq` needs index of element starting from `0`. So if you want to append first one, use `0`, second, use `1`, third, use `2` and so on.

If you want to clone first or last, use `:first` and `:last` filter selectors:

```
// clone first
$('.immediate-whiskypack-inputs:first').clone().appendTo('#whiskypacks').show();
$('.immediate-whiskypack-inputs').eq(0).clone().appendTo('#whiskypacks').show();
// clone last
$('.immediate-whiskypack-inputs:last').clone().appendTo('#whiskypacks').show();
```

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention which `div` you want to clone, so I guess you don't care which one...
`first()` function will grab the first element:

```
$('.addPack').click(function(){
            $('.immediate-whiskypack-inputs').first().clone().appendTo('#whiskypacks').show();
            return false;
       });
```

If you do care which element you want to clone, use the `eq(index)` function:

```
$('.immediate-whiskypack-inputs').eq(theDesiredElementIndex).clone()...
```

`eq` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

> eq(index) index- An integer indicating the **0-based position of the element.**

Comment: He didn't mention first div actually :)

Comment: @Sarfraz. Well _"just one of the div's?"_ sounds like he doesn't care which one... But I added `eq` in sake of completeness...